# Jmeter- iOS app recording doesn't work for Native app

Tags: ios, iphone, jmeter, native, recording

I have an iOS app for which performance has to be monitored.I have done the required settings for Jmeter setup in Mobile device(Setting up proxy,certificate installation etc) but some action recording works and for some it doesn't work e.g Login.

I have tried using these different ways
1.I have tried recording the app from different network apart from current settings
2.I have tried using Blaze meter to record app
3.I have tried recording from Windows and Mac device.

Could anyone provide any suggestion on what might be the reason for failure.
JMeter version 5.2.1
Java 9.0.4
iOS 14.2

Answer (score 0):

1. As per [Recording Using Apple Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285377-Recording-Using-Apple-Devices-Recording-Using-Apple-Devices) guide you need to [enable full trust](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT204477) for the JMeter's certificate

   [image]
2. Also make sure that the certificate is still valid (i.e. not expired) as it's life time is [7 days only](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert)

If the above steps don't help - check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it normally contains sufficient troubleshooting information.